# Presenting a modal view controller immediately after dismissing another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm dismissing a modal view controller and then immediately presenting another one, but the latter never happens. Here's the code:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

The first modal VC slides down, but the new `picker` never comes up. Any idea as to what's going on?

Comment: It's not good idea to create new instance of UIImagePickerController, can you use the old one ?

Comment: can you expand on this? why would it be a bad idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like other animated things, `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` doesn't block until the view controller disappears. Instead it "kicks off" dismissal of the view controller. You might need to use a callback in `viewDidDisappear` of modal controller 1 that calls something like `modalViewControllerDisappeared` in the parent view controller. In that method you present modal controller 2. Otherwise what Robot K said.

Comment: That's a good idea. I might try it the next time I have to do this.

Comment: Not sure it will work (I didn't test it) but it seems like it should.

Comment: I tried to use the event driven approach recommended in this answer, placing the callback in `viewDidDisappear`, and the race condition persisted.  See my answer on this question for the solution that eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 52):

**Aug 2012 Update:**

iOS 5 and greater have introduced safer APIs for doing things *after* modals have animated into / out of place using completion blocks:

```
[self presentViewController:myModalVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

**Pre-Aug 2012 Answer:**

I encountered a similar problem when dismissing modal one and then presenting modal two in rapid succession.  Sometimes modal two would show after the modal one was dismissed and sometimes modal two wouldn't appear at all and that made me very sad.

### Looks like a race condition to me...

Putting a 1+ second delay on the caller of the method that presented modal two, `showModalTwo`, made modal two appear every time after modal one was dismissed:

```
- (void)didDismissModalOne {
    [self performSelector:@selector(showModalTwo:) 
               withObject:someNumber 
               afterDelay:1.0f];
}
```

This confirmed a suspicion that there was some sort of race condition between the dismissal of modal one and the presentation of modal two.  Putting a delay on the caller, however, is inelegant and did not guarantee that the race condition wouldn't re-appear under other circumstances.

### The problem

Turns out that `UIViewController`s have a public property, `modalViewController`, that gets set up when `presentModalViewController:animated:` is called and torn down when `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is called.  The catch is that it doesn't get torn down synchronously, so it's possible to create a race between removing the old value of `modalViewController` and setting up a new value in the following way.

1. Present modal one.  `myViewController.modalViewController` now points to modal one
2. Dismiss modal one.  Background process to tear down `myViewController.modalViewController` has started, but `myViewController.modalViewController` the still points to modal one
3. Present modal two, `myViewController.modalViewController]` now points to modal two
4. System callback fires, setting `myViewController.modalViewController` to `nil`, this interrupts the process of modal two animating in and the result is the user never sees it.

The race starts on step 2 and manifests on step 4.

### The solution

My solution was to put a guard condition on the method that presented modal two to ensure that `myViewControoler.modalViewController` was `nil` before attempting to present modal two.

```
-(void)showModalTwo:(NSNumber *)aParameter {

    if (self.modalViewController) {        
            [self performSelector:@selector(showModalTwo:)
                       withObject:aParameter 
                       afterDelay:0.1f];
            return;
    }
    // You can now present the second modal safely.
}
```

Worked like a charm.  A more elegant solution might include a timeout.

### Post script

I really didn't like the polling aspect of this solution. @Nimrod suggests, in the accepted answer to this question, that you can safely initiate the presentation of modal two from the `viewDidDisappear:` method of modal one.  I liked the sound of this event driven approach, but after doing a full implementation in my use case I confirmed that the race condition persisted when presenting modal two using a callback inside `viewDidDisappear:`.  The only way to be absolutely sure that modal two will be presented is to poll inside the parent view controller until you're absolutely sure that `self.modalViewController` is `nil`.  Then and only then is it "safe" to pop modal two.

Comment: +1 Lovely elegant solution; Especially love learning about the performSelector method... learn something new every day :-D

Comment: For those wondering why you're getting the `method not found` error using the iOS 5.0+ solution, note the difference between `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated...` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated...` (the `Modal` is now gone). Easy palm-face mistake to make.

Comment: @prairiedogg , was wondering as to what should I be passing for the "someNumber" ? I'm having some issues with mine , if you have the time i hopeyou dont mind visiting my question here regarding a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893817/ipad-modalviewcontroller-when-dismissed-does-not-go-to-the-viewdidappear-of-the

Comment: Use the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self.delegate show2ndVC];}` works for me.

Answer (score 15):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //Present the new MVC 

}];
```

Note: Available iOS 5.0 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: set animation to NO for dismissing it.

Comment: I do not think that this code will work. dismissModalViewControllerAnimated will release everything that you have in you VC and then you try to present another view controller on this VC

Comment: I hope you know that the above call from a viewcontroller does not dismiss itself. but a viewcontroller that it is currently presenting as a modal. That downvote was uncalled for, since your comment is wrong. No offense intended, but I have to be blunt here. Cheers.

Comment: Also, IronLeash, I hope you realize my answer was posted in 2010, before iOS5. The solution you have posted is available from iOS 5 onwards.... please take that into consideration.

Comment: I tried it it in a VC and it simply crashed.I wanted to call a delegate method after dismissing the views controller

Comment: Hm the crash could have been caused by something else (maybe). If you don't have a solution, post a detailed question with the code and maybe I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the view controller removes it's reference to the modal view controller once the dismiss animation is done, which happens after this code is called, so it doesn't think it has a new view controller to present modally.

How I've dealt with this is to set a `didDismissModalVC` ivar to `YES` after I call `dismissModalViewController`. Then in my `viewDidAppear:` method, I check the value of the ivar and present then new modal view controller. (Remembering to also set the value back to `NO` so I don't get stuck eternally dismissing modal view controllers.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I create delegate to callback parent view controller to show the second modal view controller.

Definition protocol of the parent view controller:

```
@protocol ParentViewControllerDelegate
- (void)showModalTwo;
@end
```

I implement this protocol in the parent view controller to show the second modal view controller and create the delegate property `@property id<ParentViewControllerDelegate> delegate;` on the first modal view controller.

Show the first modal view controller from parent view controller:

```
TheFirstModalViewController *controller = ...
controller.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
...
```

On `viewDidDisappear:` method of the first modal view controller, just call `delegate.showModalTwo:` to show the second modal view from parent view controller.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

1. Use dismissViewController to dismiss the 1st presented view.
2. Use dismissViewController's [completion block](http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/9/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift) to call a function in the mainVC. That function should call the second VC.

Your dismissViewController should look like this:

```
var presentingVC_Delegate: mainLists_PopoverDelegation!

@IBAction fund button_Pressed (sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { finished in
        self.presentingVC_Delegate.presentOtherVC()
        print("DismissVC completion block says hello")
    })
}
```

Where the mainVC houses that presentOtherVC:

```
func presentSettingsVC () {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("present_OtherVC", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach that seems to work nicely on iOS 10. My circumstance is slightly different, but should work for most situations. I'm presenting the initial viewController as a popover which requires a modal viewController to be presented immediately.

First, in the initial viewController's `viewDidLoad` simply hide it's view:

```
   view.isHidden = true
```

Then, on it's `viewWillAppear`, present the modal viewController, unanimated and un-hide the view on completion:

```
   present(yourModalViewController, animated: false) { [unowned self]
       self.view.isHidden = false
    }
```

You'll probably want to control your state with a `Bool` so that subsequent calls to `viewWillAppear` don't re-present the modal, but you get the idea.